# Making "parse" function RESTful

Tags: rest

I have a RESTful service for getting let's say devices. It provides very usual functionality:

```
GET /devices
GET /devices/:id

POST /devices

PUT /devices/:id

DELETE /devices/:id
```

The device object might be defined as follows:

```
{
    id: 123,
    name: "Smoke detector",
    firmware: "21.0.103",
    battery: "ok",
    last_maintenance: "2017-07-07",
    last_alarm: "2014-02-01 12:11:10",
    // ...
}
```

There is an application that might read device state via some device specific reader. The application itself has no idea how to interpret read data, but it might ask server to do it. In our case let's assume that the data contains the following: battery status, firmware version, last alarm.

If I were implementing regular RPC service, I would create function with "parse" meaning. It means it accept the raw data and returns an updated device object (or, alternatively, only the part of the device object containing the parsed state). But I doubt that I could find a good REST solution for such function. Now I am doing it via PATCH, but I personally do not like this solution, and therefore I will not provide it here. I believe there should be good solution for such class of problems.

So the question: how should I fit my "parse" logic in REST paradigm?

Comment: As a rule of thumb on almost any question regarding REST: how would you do it if you were implementing it for a web server? The same principals that apply for the Web also apply to REST. The biggest difference between these two is the representation format used in the response.

Comment: Thank you for the rule! But you actually do it slightly different in Web. I can imagine how I would do it in the Web, but not sure I can map it on the REST quite well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`POST` it to a `/parsed-device-state` URL, which will return a `201 Created`, a `Location` header pointing to the place where you can get the parsed data from, and if you like, return the parsed data in the 201 as well (along with an additional `Content-Location` header with the same value as the `Location` header). Or if it takes a long time to parse, use `202 Accepted`, and the same `Location` header. The caller can then poll that provided location until the results are ready.

Comment: I was thinking about something similar, but I don't really happy with it as well. I actually have a resource device (which already contains a state). Introducing another resource `parsed-device-state`, which never exist, a bit unsound for me.

Comment: REST is more about stateful URLs, typed hyperlinks between them, and using the protocol correctly than about trying to create a perfect model. Resources (URIs) are easy to create and maintain, so don't be shy about creating them.

Comment: A true RESTful architecture does (and should) NOT have [typed resources](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html). URIs are just a pointer to some resource. The architecture should not rely on certain semantics (or state) put into the generation of that pointer. A client determines whether to invoke a URI based on the link-relation name which might be something sublte like `prev`, `next`, `first` or `last` for navigating through pages of a collection. This allows APIs to change the URI model and client still be able to use the API eventhough the URI changed

Comment: @RomanVottner I don't know who you are addressing, but I referred to "typed hyperlinks", not typed resources — where the type of link is defined by its `rel` attribute. You're saying the same thing as me.

Answer (score 1):

> So the question: how should I fit my "parse" logic in REST paradigm?

How would you fit your parse logic into a web site?

You'd probably start with a *bookmark*.  `GET $BOOKMARK` would return a representation of a *form*.  The form might include an input control like a text area element that would allow the consumer to input a representation, or it might include a input control that allows the consumer to link into a file.  The consumer would submit the form, and the agent would create a request from the information in the form.  That would probably be a POST (you aren't likely to include an arbitrary file's representation onto the query string) to whatever resource was specified as the action of the form.  The server's response would provide a representation of the result.

If parsing were a particularly slow process, then the response instead might be a representation including links to resources that could be used to track the progress of the parsing.  The whole protocol in this case looks a lot like putting work on a queue, and then polling for updates.

It's the right answer to a problem that is not a great fit for HTTP:

> The REST interface is designed to be efficient for large-grain hypermedia data transfer, optimizing for the common case of the Web, but resulting in an interface that is not optimal for other forms of architectural interaction.

To some degree, what you are trying to do with your function is transfer compute, which may be why it feels like you are trimming corners off of the peg to fit it in the hole.

An *alternative* approach, which is a better fit for HTTP, is think about transferring a representation of the behavior.  The API client gets a function that understands how to parse apples into oranges, and then runs that code on the information that it keeps locally.  Think java script - we get a representation of the behavior from the server (which can embed into that representation information the server has that the client will need), and then execute the result locally.  Metadata in the headers describes the lifetime of the representation, in a way that is understood by any standards compliant cache.

Comment: Good shout-out on the optional REST constraint, transferrable code. maybe you could have just a single `/device-state-parser` URI that provides some code the client can execute. To make the results persistent and tie them to the URI, you would need to encode and store the unparsed data in fragment identifiers, and read them back out on URI load. This approach breaks "CURL-ability" though.